# Can I set a function to call a specific index from a list?

Tags: python, string, numpy-ndarray

I have `n` lists (really arrays, but I'm treating them as lists) of length `p`. I want to pull the first three values from the first, second, and third rows. This is what I have so far:

```
k0= K[0][0:3]
k1= K[1][0:3]
k2= K[2][0:3]
```

where

```
k0= [a,b,c]
k1= [d,e,f]
k2= [g,h,i]
```

such that

```
concatenated_ko = []

for j in range(0,3):
    k = "k"+str(j)
    concatenated_ko.append(k)

print(concatenated_ko)
```

which currently prints

```
['k0','k1','k2']
```

but should print

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,h,i,j]
```

Edit: I think what it boils down to is that I initially use an object from `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` which changes to `<class 'str'>`. Forcing a type change from a string to an array by `np.ndarray(k)` doesn't work either.

Any way to change it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said you *"want to pull the first three values from the first, second, and third rows"*. So instead of creating the three lists `k0`, `k1`, and `k2` separately, you could put that in your iteration and operate directly on `K`, by first slicing the first 3 columns.

**A.**

```py
concatenated_ko = []
for row in K[:3]:
    concatenated_ko.extend(row[:3])
```

**B.** or, if you want to use indexes:

```py
concatenated_ko = []
for idx in range(3):
    concatenated_ko.extend(K[idx][:3])
```

**C.** And suppose K is a 5x5 array:

```
>>> K
array([[  5,  12,  10,  70,   4],
       [102,   6, 120,  60,  22],
       [150, 100, 110,   2, 150],
       [ 15,  20,  22,  70,  30],
       [ 20,  55,   1,  70,   1]])
```

Then to get the first 3 columns of the first 3 rows as a single array, you can use [`ndarray.flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
>>> K[:3, :3].flatten()
array([  5,  12,  10, 102,   6, 120, 150, 100, 110])
>>> K[:3, :3].flatten().tolist()
[5, 12, 10, 102, 6, 120, 150, 100, 110]
```

---

Another option, **not** recommended: To make a minor modification to your original code, use `eval` to get the list from its variable name, and use `extend` instead of `append`:

```py
# with k0, k1, k2 setup as per your question
for j in range(0,3):
    k = "k"+str(j)
    concatenated_ko.extend(eval(k))
```

Comment: I flagged this one as the answer since it has more options, including one that has a theme song written by Kenny Loggins, and is overall simpler to implement (specifically the slicing operator).

Comment: lol! Should I have just said "Danger Zone" for the last one?

Comment: `eval("Danger Zone")` is actually a symlink to rm -r /home/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve `[a,b,c,d,e,f,h,i,j]` you could do the following:

```py
concatenated_ko = []
for arr in [k0, k1, k2]:
   concatenated_ko += [*arr]
```

Comment: `concatenated_ko.extend(arr)` is the more usual spelling of that.